# listing specific files in nested folders

Tags: bash, shell-script, find

I am trying to write a script which would go into two sub folders of the main path that i provide and list all the files with the extensions such as all .py documents. Following is what I have come up with so far

```
#!/bin/bash

for dir in /home/user/Desktop/Python/*/

do 
    for files in $dir 
        do 
            "list the files with .py  extension" 
        done
done
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are not required to use shell code then this can be done more easily using just `find`:

```
find /home/user/Desktop/Python -name \*.py
```

Comment: probably needs `-mindepth 2` and/or `-maxdepth 2` depending on whether .py files in the parent directory or any subdirectories are required in the output.

Comment: In what way is that _not_ shell code? It does look like a shell command line to me (at least Bourne-like, csh-like and fish, if not `rc` because of the backslash which that shell would take literally)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas That is a shell command line, yes, but except for the escaping (which is most probably not even necessary) it is the same command that would be used to call `find` from another environment. When I say "shell code" I mean something more shell-specific than just a list of simple commands. Descending into the directories within the shell and picking the wanted files with globbing would be "shell code" to me.

Comment: in other words, you mean "using only shell built-in commands".  it's completely normal for shell to use external commands for nearly everything.

Comment: @cas No, that is not what I mean. The two extremes are (1) using only simple commands without any shell stuff and (2) using only shell stuff. The typical shell script does both. I would not call case (1) shell code.

Comment: I am required of doing it in shell script. The commands that you are suggesting are indeed very simple and succinct, but i was just trying to demonstrate looping for what is essentially going to be just a demonstration for a job interview